# How to run the ordered tests from the code

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a set of tests(around 30) which i have to run multiple times,
by changing certain configurations. My idea is to create an ordered test containing all the 30 methods and want to run this.
I want to know if i can do that. i could not get any help from google search results. :(

Comment: what do you use for unit testing?

Comment: Visual Studio. But I am recently into this. so checking out possible things but seems very randomly. :)

Comment: Are you relying on built-in Microsoft test framework ? Or NUnit/MBUnit within Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

Provided test1(), test2()... are your already existing test methods, how about something like this:

```
[Test]
public void run_all_confs()
{
   test_in_conf1();
   test_in_conf2();
}

public void test_in_conf1()
{
   setup_conf1();
   run_tests();
}

public void test_in_conf2()
{
   setup_conf2();
   run_tests();
}

public void run_tests()
{
   test1();
   test2();
   // ...
   test30();
}
```

You should be able to port this in any test environment I know about.

Comment: I would add `[Test]` attribute to the methods `test_in_conf1` and `test_in_conf2` instead. And remove `run_all_confs`. That's my understanding of unit-testing - tests should be as small as possible.

Comment: @Snowbear: You're correct, if the configuration runs can be run in any order. As I didn't know if this was the case, I chose to propose a safer way.

Comment: @Snowbear: From a different perspective, having tests that have to be run in a certain order tests is usually a smell. :-)

Comment: Thanks dude, I thought of this but I also want to know if ordered tests can be used from code. Because I don't want to type all the method names, and by the way ordered tests allows us to add or modify the methods or their order so easily. :)

Comment: @Em - completely agree with both comments :) I just wish to topicstarter to have 2 'unit'-tests instead of 1 ;)

Comment: @Prakash: "can be used from code" -> I'm not sure to understand what you're after. Could you give an example of what you expect ?

Comment: @Em: Ordered tests are separate entities and can be run only from Test List Editor. i want to call them from a method or application anything like that.

Comment: @Prakash: Could you update your question with all of those elements ? Could you also add the client pseudo code ("i want to call them from a method or application anything like that.") you'd like to see working ?

Comment: @Em: you are having an idea on Ordered tests in visual studio, right.. They run a collections of tests in an order additionally they have many features like handling exceptions, running testCleanup and testInitialise methods implicitly. They generally have an extension (.orderedtest), I am not really sure how to call them from a normal test. I just wanted to say that psuedo won't really help you.

Comment: @Prakash: Now, I got it. How about relying on triggering the [mstest.exe runner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=VS.100).aspx) ? You could launch it from a .cmd/.bat command or from code through a Process.Start().

Comment: @Em: Right now MSDN is down. any other source, i can look into to know more about mstest.exe. I am not quite aware of using this. :(

Comment: @Prakash: how about [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22MSTest.exe+Command-Line+Options%22) ;-) ?

Comment: Thats cool.. :P, i was using that but just asked if you have went through post or something like that. leave it, i got some info